# I have an issue with for loop. It is not executing

Tags: for-loop

What is wrong with the code below

```
def square(n):
    return n*n

def sum_squares(x):
    sum = 0
    for n in sum:
        sum += -1
    return x

print(sum_squares(10)) # Should be 285
```

Comment: can you explain what you're trying to do with the code?

Comment: What did you expect? What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you wanted to sum all the squares of the numbers less than x.
So instead of returning x in the second function, you should return sum. And of course, calculate sum using your "square" function:

```
def square(n):
    return n*n

def sum_squares(x):
    int sum = 0
    for i in range(x):
        sum += square(i)
    return sum
```